# Openstack Heat and Kubernetes Deployment Integration

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, openstack-heat

I want to create an Openstack cluster with HEAT and deploy kubernetes on it, how to **integrate HEAT with Kubernetes**, any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [magnum](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum) service is what you are looking for, since it allows you to create and manage not only `kubernetes` clusters but also other container orchestrator engines such as `docker swarm` or `mesos`, being fully integrated in OpenStack.

Indeed, in its core, magnum uses heat to deploy and configure the nodes of the cluster, so if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, give it a go: ([Install guide](https://docs.openstack.org/magnum/latest/install/index.html)).